I only asked 2 questions - how come I am on a question ban?
I have asked 2 questions, and when I tried to ask another I got a question ban. Is my performance from other SE sites effecting me here?

The question ban (and answer ban) is in this case decided by the bot. As as far as I know, user-activity on one site doesn't affect question/answer bans on others. For instance, your Bio account is still fully functional. 
The fact that your banned from the main site is probably because of the latest downvote(s) here. Overall your posts have gathered a negative vote tally, enough for the bot to act. You can read more on it here in the help center.  
And for that matter - you asked three questions, including a deleted one, namely Would SE have a voting war? [closed] that's probably not visible for you any longer. This question received three downvotes.   
